# Laravel - Search Field for multiple tables

Tags: laravel, search, scope, eloquent

I'm trying to search a string inside multiple models.

I made a search button for just one table and thats work very well. But can not entegrate to multiple table. How can i do that?

in My NewsController:

```
    $query = $request->get('q');
    $new = $request->filled('q') ? News::search($query) : News::query();
    $new = $new->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

in My Model:

```
public function scopeSearch(Builder $query, $search)
{
    $query->whereHas('translations', function ($q) use ($search) {
        $q->where('value', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    })->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('sub_body', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
}
```

And this is the view:

```
<form name="searchForm" method="get" action="{{route('news_blade')}}">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="q" class="search-input">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your search query would reproduce the following mysql query "select * from `news` where exists (select * from `translations` where `news`.`id` = `translations`.`news_id` and `value` like ?) or `title` LIKE ? or `sub_body` like ? or `body` like ?" . This query would return a collection of News models, but your search term might be somewhere in the collection of a Model $new->translations (which contains all specified model's translations, even if only one of the translations.value contain the search term).

Comment: translations.value contains all tables translated languages values. There is no problem for that. I just need to extend the query with another models.